# Macport self update failed

Tags: macports

```
ginnyweasley:~ s66$ sudo port selfupdate
Password:
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

I have tried to redownload macports and it still does not seem to work. I have also tried it without sudo and it still does not work. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I had that problem too.  Even, like you, I re-downloaded the distribution and reinstalled.

That is until I read the manpage and tried the '-d' flag so

> sudo port -d selfupdate

I tried it and surprisingly didn't find a command failing but successful completion.  I didn't see any ports updated, but perhaps the error we saw were occurred after the ports tree was updated.

If it doesn't work, try it anyway, it'll at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: you may also want to add `-v` after `-d` for more verbose logging

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Yosemite, but since I found this post, I did not reinstall macports - I ran "sudo port -d selfupdate", had errors with c compiler failing, so I updated Xcode, ran "sudo port clean expat" after restarting, then ran "sudo port -d selfupdate" and all was well - thx you!