# RVM install issue - Unable to execute port (autoconf)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to install Jekyll on OSX mountain lion. First of all I wanted to install RVM and then the latest ruby. However, the RVM install is failing and I can't solve the problem. Any help appreciated

Here is what I did:

- Installed OSX Command Line Tools
- Attempted to install RVM (`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`) but it failed with an error in the log "Error: Please install Xcode and/or run xcode-select to specify its location."
- Installed XCode to see if that would help (realise now I could have used xcode-select oh well)
- Attempted to install RVM again but it failed again, see error below

**Last lines of install output including error:**

Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkgconfig, apple-gcc42, libiconv, libyaml, libffi, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite3, zlib, gdbm, ncurses...

Error running 'requirements_osx_port_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig apple-gcc42 libiconv libyaml libffi readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl curl-ca-bundle sqlite3 zlib gdbm ncurses',
please read /Users/xxx/.rvm/log/1371125385_package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkgconfig_apple-gcc42_libiconv_libyaml_libffi_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_curl-ca-bundle_sqlite3_zlib_gdbm_ncurses.log

I opened the error log and it states:

**Error: Unable to execute port: Could not open file: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/autoconf/Portfile**

This is probably obvious to someone else but frankly I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to fix it!

Answer (score 10):

Installing homebrew and then running `rvm autolibs brew`, then `rvm requirements` fixed my problem. I was then successfully able to install the latest ruby (`rvm install 2.0.0-p195`).

Still think it's hilarious I've installed Xcode, rvm, homebrew and ruby just to build a static html site :-)

Comment: Run `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"` to install homebrew

Comment: Even after installing homebrew its not fixed, then run `xcode-select --install`. Its weird that even after Xcode and command line tool is already installed we need to run it.