# MacPorts: How to run `selfupdate` offline?

Tags: installation, updates, macports

The `selfupdate` command seems to be incredibly slow in MacPorts. It seems like it is taking ages in this step

```
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from http://distfiles.macports.org/ports.tar.gz
```

I believe it is taking a long time just to download the `ports.tar.gz` file (order of 9-22 kbps). I've downloaded it myself (using `axel` downloader 100-300 kbps). How can I associate this along with `selfupdate` so that I can operate it off-line; at least for the `ports.tar.gz` file? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nailed it! Got the solution for the problem. All I had to do is to include the path in the `/opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf` file in place of the old one just like this

```
#rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar [default]
#https://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz [default]
file:////Users/Ebe/Downloads/Axel/ports.tar.gz
```

I commented out the remaining entry just in case. (Ref. the second line in the conf file was from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446923/macports-selfupdate))

I then executed `sudo port selfupdate` and the process was complete without any delay.